# FASTCGI Install on Raspberry PI Error - Cannot Manually Build Package

Tags: apache, build, fastcgi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have searched the internet all weekend and cannot find anyone who has had a similar error.  I am trying to install `libapache-mod-factcgi` but the package errors out and I cannot figure out why.

```
pi@applejacks:/tmp $ sudo apt-get source -b libapache2-mod-fastcgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Skipping already downloaded file 'libapache-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.1+deb8u1.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'libapache-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141.orig.tar.gz'
Skipping already downloaded file 'libapache-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.1+deb8u1.diff.gz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141
dpkg-buildpackage: source package libapache-mod-fastcgi
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.4.7~0910052141-1.1+deb8u1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution jessie
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Andreas Beckmann <anbe@debian.org>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture armhf
 dpkg-source --before-build libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141
 debian/rules clean
dh_listpackages: Please specify the compatibility level in debian/compat
dh_listpackages: Compatibility levels before 5 are no longer supported (level 1 requested)
/usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/dpatch.mk:33: CDBS WARNING:    dpatch.mk is deprecated since 0.4.85 - please use source format 3.0 (quilt) instead
test -x debian/rules
rmdir /tmp/libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141/build-tmp
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/tmp/libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141/build-tmp’: No such file or directory
/usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/buildcore.mk:46: recipe for target 'cleanbuilddir' failed
make: [cleanbuilddir] Error 1 (ignored)
dh_clean 
dh_clean: Please specify the compatibility level in debian/compat
/usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk:189: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
Build command 'cd libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to build Apache2 on RPi also.  These commands got the `.deb` building for me:

```
cd libapache-mod-fastcgi-2.4.7~0910052141;
echo 10 > debian/compat;
dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

Then `cd ..` to go one level up, then install the package with `dpkg -i ./libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.1+deb8u1_armhf.deb`

Comment: I replicated this, and can confirm that it works. The only reason I haven't voted on it is because I don't understand exactly why.